# How Linux Scheduler knows that a process has run for defined time slice?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I am unable to understand How Linux Scheduler knows that process has run for defined time slice. Does timer interrupt keep on coming during process execution ?

Lets take a scenario, HZ is 100, so there will be a tick in every 10 milliseconds. Now assume there are only process with same priority, so both should get equal chance, so if time slice is 4 ms, both process will run for that much time. My doubt is how scheduler will know that process has consumed its 4 ms ?

Comment: Yes. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: could you please elaborate.

Comment: Not unless you ask a more specific question.

Comment: I have modified the question.

Comment: I thought time slice can't be less than a tick, on every timer interrupt kernel will schedule new process, isn't it ?

Comment: @AnkurTank A time slice is generally quite a bit *more* than one tick.  However, only 100% CPU-bound processes consume their entire timeslice, and *any* interrupt - not just the timer interrupt - gives the scheduler an opportunity to consider giving "the" CPU to someone else.  (For instance, the keyboard driver's interrupts will cause the scheduler to activate whatever process is waiting for keyboard input, taking the CPU away from processes that aren't if necessary.)

Comment: Thank you @Zack that informative and nicely explained.+1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel timer is always running and interrupting processes. As part of its management duties the kernel keeps track of how many full (and partial) time slices a process consumes. Now, there are many things which will cause a process to give up part of a time slice. These are generically referred to as blocking events (though not all blocking events give up the remainder of a time slice and return control to the kernel). Whenever you call `sleep`, or wait for user input or for disk or network I/O, the kernel doesn't just spin in a loop consuming the rest of your time slice before switching to the next task. Instead it adds the amount of time from the partially consumed slice to your processes information store and goes on to the process in its list. Then, when the event on which you were waiting occurs, your process is queued up to become active at the next opportunity and given a new full time slice. This continues until the process terminates by any means.